# How can I access network device counters such as tx/rcv packets/bytes from kernel code?

Tags: network-programming, linux-kernel

I'm writing a driver and I want to get network counters of some device within it.
What data structure holds that information and how can I access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use [dev_get_by_name](http://kernelbook.sourceforge.net/kernel-api.html/r2489.html) to get a pointer to the struct net_device of the interface.

Then, the net_device structure has a pointer to the [stats](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch14.html#t3) function, which is declared as:

```
struct net_device_stats *(*get_stats)(struct net_device *dev);
```

The [net_device_stats](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch14.html#t12) structure contains the information you want.